# flutter : how to fix The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fix errors on my project after migration to null safety . i have error on this line :

```
 opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]  ), child: child),
```

error : The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

My code :

```
class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay,   this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity")
          .add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateY").add(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -130.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    return ControlledAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builderWithChild: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]  ), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How I can fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your object `animation` might be `null` (I guess its type is `Map?`).
So you cannot do `animation['yourKey']` directly as `null['yourKey']` is not valid.

You have several solutions:

1. Try to change the type of `animation` to `Map` if possible.
2. If `animation` has to be `Map?` but you are sure it won't be `null` when you use it, you can do

```dart
animation!['yourKey']
```

3. If it can be `null` then you can do:

```dart
animation?['yourKey'], // If it is okay to use a `null` value here
animation?['yourKey'] ?? defaultValue, // If you need to use a non-null value
```

---

For example, for you opacity you can to:

```dart
opacity: animation?["opacity"] ?? 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using nullsafety

```
final double? delay;
final Widget? child;
```

then for calling them will be end at !

e.g delay! or child!